# MethodAccessException by using private methods of DLLs

Tags: c#

I have a Access issue by calling a private Method of an DLL.
The DLL has a reference to another DLL, which is loaded too.

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\\Path\\to\\OtherDLL.dll");
var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\\Path\\to\\MyDLL.dll");
var type2 = asm.GetType("ClassOfDLL");
var mi = type2.GetMethod("privateMethodOfDLL", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { ParameterOfMethod }); // MethodAccessException is called here
```

Following exception is called:

```
MethodAccessException: Error when attempting the method "MyDll.privateMethodOfDLL(System.String)", to access "OtherDLL.OtherPrivateMethod(System.String, Boolean, System.String[])".
```

The DLLs are working together in another project (which isn't mine, and I have no sourcecode).

How can I manage that privateMethodOfDLL from MyDLL can access the OtherPrivateMethod of OtherDLL in my project?

Comment: Only because you load two assemblies into memory doesn´t make them known to each other. If `MyADll` references the other one, it surely does so by a specific path which is baked into `MyDll`. Of yourse `OtherDll` has to be located at that path.

Comment: Maybe the first DLL was compiled when the second DLL's method was still public? I'd say you should focus on writing good code, instead of trying to call a private through another private. Don't chain hacks, build a solid solution.

Comment: The DLLs are also referenced in my VisualStudio Project. So the first answer is done, right?
The second answer is good and understandable, but not implementable for me, because I'm not the source code owner of the DLLs.
I hope, there is another way to get the thing working?

Comment: @HimBromBeere That would cause an `AssemblyResolutionException`. This one is usually caused by calling private methods from untrusted code, when running in a sandbox.

Comment: @Charlieface: Thanks for your answer, but my code isn't running in a specific sandbox. It's a very small program, only the few lines of code in a Main function.

Comment: Is it a UWP / Windows Store app? Or it might be the parameters, which don't seem to match.